# Binding set to CheckBoxes in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

using Entity Framework (C#) I have a `User` class which has `ONE:MANY` mapping to the `UserRight` class (simply, user has a set of rights). Each right is identified by a string. And now, because the maximum number of possible rights is finite (<10) I'd like to have 10 `CheckBoxes` and edit the subset of rights for a given user manually.

What is the nice way to do it?

James

Comment: checkboxes gives you a bool, your userrights are strings - so what you wanna do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `RightViewModel` class to contain user rights:

```
public class RightViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            Change("Name");
        }
    }

    private bool _hasRight;
    public bool HasRight
    {
        get { return _hasRight; }
        set
        {
            _hasRight = value;
            Change("HasRight");
        }
    }

    public void Change(string strPropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(strPropertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Create a similar class for your user, containing a member `Rights`of type `ObservableCollection<RightViewModel>`.

In you XAML, use an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rights}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RightTemplate}"/>
```

And a template definition:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RightTemplate">
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding HasRight, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

`Mode=TwoWay` makes the binding update your `RightViewModel` instance.

Define the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemsPanel` if you need to display your checkboxes with a different layout.

Finally set your user as the `DataContext` of your container.